# How to change order of network adaptors in windows task manager?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-8, task-manager

Is there any way to change the order of network adapters in the networking tab of windows task manager? (Either Win 7 or 8)

I know that disabling the network adapter will take it away from the list (think about the Bluetooth Network Adapter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first adapter listed is whichever one is first in your binding order.  If you open up Network and Sharing Center, click Change Adapter settings to list your adapters.  Then, hit the ALT key to bring up the menu bar.  Under the Advanced menu, choose Advanced Settings.  The first tab is your Adapters and Bindings tab.  Under the Connections list, move your primary adapter to the top of the list.

Note that this change affects more than just the way they're listed in Task Manager.  But it only comes into play if your computer is connected to two different networks at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! I am familiar with bindings, but I did not know that affects the order of appearance. Works perfect both on Win 7 and 8. I wish it was independent of binding order through (think about the time where you connect to your work network both on Wifi and Gigabit).